# C# MVC Controller passing null date

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have an ASP.net MVC application.  It uses a bootstrap navbar to navigate between two forms.  I'm passing a date from a datepicker to a C# function, but it doesn't work on page load if there is no date entered into the datepicker.  I'm not sure how to compensate if there is no date to pass.  It should take today's date if there is no date in the datepicker.  I'm not getting an error message, it just doesn't work.  Here is my view:

```
<div class="row-fluid 1">
    <div class="col-lg-12 delayed_spiff_body">

        <div class="row spiff-datepicksection">
            <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-offset-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <input type="text" id="startDate" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <input class="spiffdate-btn" type="button" value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
<div class="row spiff_tabs_body">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs spiff_tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-id="delayedspiff" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/delayedspiff', 'delayedspiff')">Potential Spiff</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-id="instantspiff" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/instantspiff', 'delayedspiff')">Instant Spiff</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="delayedspiff"></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="instantspiff"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
    FormGet('dashboard/delayedspiff', 'delayedspiff');
});
</script>

<script>
   $(".spiffdate-btn").click(function(){
   var correctId = $("ul.spiff_tabs li.active a").attr('data-id');
   console.log(correctId);

   var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
   if (startDate == "") {

   } else {
       if (correctId == "delayedspiff")
       {          
           $.get("@Url.Action("DelayedSpiff", "Dashboard")", { startDate: startDate });

       } else if (correctId = "instantspiff") {

           $.get("@Url.Action("InstantSpiffDate", "Dashboard")", { startDate: startDate });
       }    
   }         
});
</script>
```

Here's part of my code in my controller, that should have the date passed to it.

```
public ActionResult DelayedSpiff(DateTime startDate)
    {
        var available = _appService.GetFeatureStatus(1, "spiffDashboard");
        if (!available)
            return RedirectToAction("DatabaseDown", "Error", new { area = "" });

        //var startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6);

        if (startDate == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6);
        }
        else
        {
            startDate = startDate.AddDays(-7);
        }            

        var acctId = User.AccountID;

        var endDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1); // 1

        Dictionary<DateTime, List<SpiffSummaryModel>> dict = new Dictionary<DateTime,List<SpiffSummaryModel>>();

        try
        {
            var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Type", "DelayedSpiff" }
            };
            telemetry.TrackEvent("Dashboard", properties);

            dict = _reportingService.GetDailyDelayedSpiffSummaries(acctId, startDate, endDate);
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm guessing it has something to do with the FormGet function. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just make startDate nullable in your Action?

```
public ActionResult DelayedSpiff(DateTime? startDate)
```

Then just handle this in your code.

```
if (!startDate.HasValue || startDate.Value == DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6);
    }
    else
    {
        startDate = startDate.Value.AddDays(-7);
    }
```

then you could remove

```
if (startDate == "") {

} else {
```

Comment: Hi JamieD77.  I'm getting an error on startDate = startDate.AddDays(-7);  It says Error 13 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'AddDays' and no extension method 'AddDays' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you can create a new variable or just always use startDate.Value.AddDays

Comment: Ok that worked, but now on this line dict = _reportingService.GetDailyDelayedSpiffSummaries(acctId, startDate, endDate);  I'm getting the error message Error 22 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: same thing.. use startDate.Value

Comment: I figured that out right after I posted my comment.  :)  it's working!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the input is empty, then your code *explicitly* does nothing:

```
var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
if (startDate == "") {

}
```

If you want to invoke the server-side action regardless of the contents of the input, then just remove that conditional entirely and perform the logic that's currently in the `else` block.

Comment: David, It still doesn't work.  It doesn't load the form at all if I take out those lines in the javascript code.

Comment: @hollyquinn: Can you clarify the problem a bit more.  "doesn't load the form at all" isn't really descriptive.  What *does* happen?  What, specifically, are you trying to do here and where exactly does it fail?

Comment: sure.  What happens is the page loads with a bootstrap navtab.  Depending on which tab you are on it displays a different form.  When the form loads the actionresult DelayedSpiff runs and populates a table with data.  There is a datepicker on the screen that allows the user to pick a date and display a range of data for that date.  If there is no date in the datepicker the form should load for today's date.  The problem I'm  having is that if there is no date in the datepicker when the form loads, it doesn't run the action result DelayedSpiff.  Does that make more sense?  Thanks.

Comment: @hollyquinn: Are you talking about this function call?: `FormGet('dashboard/delayedspiff', 'delayedspiff');`  You haven't shown what `FormGet()` is or does, so I can't really help with that.  (If it's built-in to one of the frameworks you're using, I'm not familiar with it.)  Either way, you're going to have to do at least *some* debugging here.  Nobody here can do that for you.  What client-side code is making the AJAX request?  Is the request made?  What is the server's response?  If it isn't made, what is preventing it from being made?